# A hump in understanding the proof for the set of algebraic numbers forming a field

Tags: modules, algebraic-number-theory

Rosen and Ireland write as part of the proof the following.

> Suppose that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are algebraic numbers. We shall show that $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ and $\alpha_1\alpha_2$ are algebraic numbers. Suppose that $\alpha_1^n + r_1\alpha_1^{n-1} + r_2\alpha_1^{n-2} + \ldots + r_n = 0 $ and $\alpha_2^m + s_1\alpha_2^{m-1} + s_2\alpha_2^{m-2} + \ldots + s_m = 0$ with $r_i,s_j \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $V$ be the $\mathbb{Q}$ module obtained by forming all $\mathbb{Q}$ linear combinations of the elements $\alpha_1^i\alpha_2^j$, where $0 \leq i < n$ and $0 \leq j < m$. For $\gamma \in V$ we have $\alpha_1\gamma \in V$ and $\alpha_2\gamma \in V$ (prove it).

It is this "prove it" part that I couldn't prove. If $\gamma \in V,$ then $\gamma = \sum _{0 \leq i <n, \: 0 \leq j < m} a_{ij}\alpha_1^i\alpha_2^j$ where $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{Q}$. This would imply that if you multiple $\gamma$ by $\alpha_1$, then you would have a term with $\alpha_1^n$, which is not allowed by the definition of $V$. So how is it true that $\alpha_1\gamma \in V$?

Comment: What's the difference between $\Bbb Q$-module and $\Bbb Q$-vector space?

Comment: @KennyLau I think it's that the module is necessarily finite dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You eliminate the $\alpha_1^n$ term through the relation
$$\alpha_1^n=-r_1\alpha_1^{n-1}-r_2\alpha_1^{n-2}-\cdots-r_n.$$